# XML Layout: Forcing a block to go last

Tags: layout, blocks

In XML layouts, is there a way of ensuring a block you are adding goes last?

I am aware of `before=""` and `after=""` for positioning a block relative to other blocks.

I was wondering if there was a way of forcing a block to be the last one rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put after="-" to put a block in last position.
Remember that this only work if parent block is a core/text_list (structural).

If you put before="-" the block will be the first one.

Regards